# How to generating QR-Codes for permalinks in forums?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, qr-code, permalinks, userscripts

I would like to use QR-codes to streamline the browsing of certain forums with my android smartphone.

I'm looking for a Greasemonkey script that places a QR code next to every permalink, of every post, on a forum thread.

I've got a bit of a template to work from, the YouTube 'share' QR script:

```
var shareBoxCheckInterval   = setInterval (AddQR_Code, 200);

function AddQR_Code () {
var shareDiv    = document.querySelector ('.share-option-container .ytg-box');
if (shareDiv) {
    var qrIMG   = 'http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chl=' 
                + window.location.href + '&chld=M%7C0&cht=qr&chs=125x125';
    var img     = document.createElement ('img');
    img.src     = qrIMG;
    img.width   = 125;
    img.height  = 125;
    shareDiv.appendChild (img);
    clearInterval (shareBoxCheckInterval);
    }
}
```

What this does is it adds a QR code to Youtube's sharebox, like so:

[image: Qr code sample result]

for easy video transfer from PC to phone.

How do I adapt this code to work with forum permalinks, and *replace* the link's text with a QR code image?

For example, on [this thread on the Minecraft forum](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/773756-beginner-guide-and-faq/), there is a small link to the top right of every post saying '#1','#2','#3', ad infinitum -- which links to that particular post.

What the userscript would do, is replace the text saying '#1' with a QR code image (generated by the Google API) linking to that post, while also being a clickable hyperlink image (also linking to that post).

It would then repeat this for every permalink on the page.

Would this be possible, and if so, how?

Comment: Yes, it should be possible. (1) Use `querySelectorAll()` or jQuery to get a list of the post links. (2) Loop through that list calling `AddQR_Code()` -- but modified to use the link's href instead of `location.href`.

Comment: Just two questions, 
1: how would it know where to REplace the QR code?
2: how would i make the QR image so that it still links to the permalink when i click it?

Comment: (1) It would be placed relative to the list item. Search for "DOM traversal".  (2) You wouldn't just insert an image, you'd wrap it in a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here's **a complete script** that loops through the post bookmarks and adds QR codes.

I left the post-numbers in because they are useful to me on the forums I use.  If you really want them gone, add `$(this).text (" ");` just before the `$(this).append (...` line.

Note the use of CSS for styling (good), not tag attributes (evil).

The script is slightly complicated with needing the `withPages_jQuery` structure to make it compatible with Google Chrome (as indicated by the [userscripts](/questions/tagged/userscripts) tag).

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        _Minecraft Forum, post barcodizer
// @namespace   _pc
// @include     http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/*
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

function GM_scriptMain ($) {
    var postBkMarks = $("div.post_block div.post_wrap h3 span.post_id a");
    postBkMarks.each ( function () {
        var qrIMG   = 'http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chl='
                    + encodeURIComponent (this.href)
                    + '&chld=M%7C0&cht=qr&chs=125x125'
                    ;
        $(this).append ('<img src="' + qrIMG + '">');
    } );
}

withPages_jQuery (GM_scriptMain);

GM_addStyle (
    "h3 span.post_id a img {width: 125px; height: 125px;}"
);

function withPages_jQuery (NAMED_FunctionToRun) {
    //--- Use named functions for clarity and debugging...
    var funcText        = NAMED_FunctionToRun.toString ();
    var funcName        = funcText.replace (/^function\s+(\w+)\s*\((.|\n|\r)+$/, "$1");
    var script          = document.createElement ("script");
    script.textContent  = funcText + "\n\n";
    script.textContent += 'jQuery(document).ready(function() {'+funcName+'(jQuery);});';
    document.body.appendChild (script);
};
```

(Works in FF/GM, Chrome, Tampermonkey, and other browsers).

---

---

The **Firefox (Greasemonkey) - only** version (and probably Tampermonkey) is simpler:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        _Minecraft Forum, post barcodizer
// @namespace   _pc
// @include     http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/*
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

var postBkMarks = $("div.post_block div.post_wrap h3 span.post_id a");
postBkMarks.each ( function () {
    var qrIMG   = 'http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chl='
                + encodeURIComponent (this.href)
                + '&chld=M%7C0&cht=qr&chs=125x125'
                ;
    $(this).append ('<img src="' + qrIMG + '">');
} );

GM_addStyle (
    "h3 span.post_id a img {width: 125px; height: 125px;}"
);
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! :D

I just have some more questions :P

1) How do i make it so that it doesn't offset the entire infobar downward? (It causes the 'Posted 04 August etc.' text to sometimes be [overlapped by large fonts](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1398968-132forgemodloadersspsmp-davidees-updated-13-mods-autojoinpainting-gui-mob-spawn-controls-note-guitoggle-sneaksprint/))
2) Is it possible to have there be a textbox stating the post's number when moving over the QR with your mouse?
and 3) There is an ugly little white area around every QR, is this google's doing or can i remove it?

Comment: Basically, making it look like [this](http://s9.postimage.org/5slnu96nz/Minecraftforumprettyqr.png)


Btw, thanks for the edit, i was a bit tired when i wrote that :)
OH and yeah, to be able to see the overlapping you'd obviously need to have the script enabled >.<

Comment: You're welcome. As for your additional questions, they **are additional questions**, not covered by the scope of this question.  It gets annoying when too many "change orders" are piled onto... well anything, really.  Items 1 and 2 are more CSS and HTML issues.  Item 3 is Google's doing (and may be necessary for QR codes to function properly, maybe) -- but it can be ameliorated with CSS.   ...   So, mark this question as answered (as it *is*, as originally posed). Then ask items 1-3 in a *new* HTML/CSS/Greasemonkey(and/or)Userscripts question. I will see it (as will others who can answer).